# Flutter: Execution failed for task ':location:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: android, dart, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, dart-pub

I'm trying to build the release variant of my flutter app but i got this gradle error. Please help

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:                                                              Execution failed for task ':location:verifyReleaseResources'.
>
> > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource
> >     linking failed
> >     /Users/omotayo/lasumonitor/build/location/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:276:
> >     error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
> >     /Users/omotayo/lasumonitor/build/location/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:277:
> >     error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.   error: failed
> >     linking references.
> >     * Try:                                                                          Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
> >     or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
> >     insights.

Answer (score 2):

- In Android Studio (with your project open) right click the android
  folder, and click "Flutter"->"Open Android Module in Android Studio".
  Select "Open in New Window"
- In the new window, expand "Gradle Scripts"
- Locate "build.gradle" for all modules
- In each of the gradle scripts, modify the `compileSdkVersion` from
  27->28.
- Search for `<uses-sdk>` tag in AndroidManifest files and remove.

Save the changes and build the signed apk (release version).